# Numpy: fill conditional subarray with increasing numbers

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I often come across an idiom like the following: say I have data like

```
N = 20                             # or some other number
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, N)    # or any other 1D np.array
predicate = lambda x: x%2 == 0     # or any other predicate
```

The idiom I encounter is along the lines

```
b = np.full_like(a, -1)
i1 = 0
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if predicate(x):
        b[i] = i1
        i1 += 1
```

How do I translate this to numpy? The following:

```
b = np.full_like(a, -1)
m = some_predicate(a)
b[m] = np.arange(np.count_nonzero(m))
```

looks a bit odd to me: this is three lines for such a simple task.  In particular, it disturbs me that I need to store `m`, which I do since I need to reference it twice (because I have no way to say "arange with as many values as necessary").

Comment: *"arange with as many values as necessary"* is a complex thing that would require some kind of generator, and that's not something like you would find in `numpy` standard functions.

Comment: There is nothing that stops you from doing this in two lines, `b = ...; b[some_predicate(a)] = np.arange(some_predicate(a).shape[1])`, but this should be truly horrifying. I'm not convinced that "simple task" < 3 lines, which is already an improvement over the first approach. Performance wise too.

Comment: By the way, `a` as defined is a single number and not a 1d array. Even for a 1d array, m would then also have the same shape, so `m.shape[1]` wouldn't make sense. But with `a` being a 1d array, it seems like your actual intention should have been `b[m] = np.arange(np.count_nonzero(m))`.

Comment: @Reti43 The proposed line (which you already call horrifying) evaluates the predicate twice on `a`. I think I don't understand what you're saying in the rest of your first comment; could you phrase that differently? Regarding your second post: you're right; changed.

Comment: I feel like you're getting hung up over how many lines a simple task should be. By the way, this isn't a straightforward task and it's elegant that it can be done in 3 lines. Why would you be disturbed at storing a reference to something that you need to use more than once? First approach: python level loops are slow and you call a function N times. Second approach: one call function and numpy operations applied on the whole array at once = fast.

Answer (score 0):

Walrus operator to the rescue (starting with Python 3.8):

```
i = -1
b = np.array([ -1 if not predicate(val) else (i := i+1) for val in a ])
```

or (presumably significantly faster for large arrays)

```
b = np.full_like(a, -1)
b[sel] = np.arange(np.count_nonzero(sel := predicate(a)))
```